# Getting a return without being exact

Tags: ruby

I have the following code and the return values give me either empty brackets or the name if I give the exact name. How do I get it so that it returns multiple values without having to put in the exact name?

```
def self.find_all_by_name(name)
  result = self.all.select {|thing| thing.name == name}
  result
end
```

Comment: Tip: In a method `x = ...; x` is the same as just the `...` part due to the implicit `return`.

Comment: Is this ActiveRecord (Rails) code?

Comment: don't believe so, I'm still new to ruby and haven't learn rails yet

Comment: What is `self`? What is `self.all`? Is this backed by a database?

Comment: this was just a chunk of the rb file

Comment: That doesn't help establish context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just plain Ruby code, which would be odd, then you can simplify it:

```rb
def self.find_all_by_name(name)
  self.all.select { |thing| thing.name == name }
end
```

If that doesn't return the correct list of objects then you should verify that your names actually match. One way to test is to dump out the result of:

```
p self.all.map(&:name)
```

Check that name matches *exactly*, as differences in case or additional spaces will cause a string match to fail.

If you want a "contains" type match, you can do:

```rb
def self.find_all_by_name(name)
  self.all.select { |thing| thing.name.include?(name) }
end
```

### ActiveRecord

If this is ActiveRecord code, or ORM code of some kind, then this ends up loading every record from the database, instantiating models for each one, then comparing the name property. **Hugely inefficient and can crash your application, hard** if you have a sufficiently large number of records.

What you probably want is to *scope* things, which is actually way easier:

```rb
where(name: name)
```

Note that the `find_all_by_name` method should be auto-generated and do exactly this, anyway, or you can do `find_by(name: name)` just the same.

Comment: thank you! I realized what I was doing wrong and it was super simple. I was putting thing.include? not thing.name.include?     So dumb. Thank you again haha

Comment: Upvote anything that helps, and accept answers that solve your problem when you can. Glad that worked out!

Comment: @tadman : What's the point in prefixing `self` in front of `add` here? If I understand it correctly, `def self.` makes it a class method, and the `self` inside the method body simply denotes the class itself. Right?

Comment: @user1934428 Do you mean like `self.all` or `def self.find_all_by_name`? If the former, that's just to make it clear `all` is a method call, not a variable, but it can usually be omitted. If the latter, that's a "class method" where you can call it directly on the class, like `Example.find_all_by_name` vs. having to call on an instance of `Example`.

Comment: That's my point. I would have written simply `all`. I guess the OP know why he was making it a class method, but it confused me that he redundandtly used the `self` in front of `all`, and since you copied that in your answer, I was wondering whether I am missing something here....